# R: power calculation for beta coefficient

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I am interested in calculating the power for the beta effect size, for example

```
Call:
lm(formula = log1p(y) ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5684 -0.1881 -0.0413  0.1494  1.2312 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.59725    0.02460  24.279   <2e-16 ***
x           -0.06087    0.05514  -1.104     0.27    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2551 on 1667 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0007306, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0001312 
F-statistic: 1.219 on 1 and 1667 DF,  p-value: 0.2697
```

So, the beta (effect size) for x here is -0.06087. Can I calculate the power of detecting current effect size with two-tailed significant level of 0.05 in the following equation

```
Z(power)=abs(beta)/se-1.96=0.06087/0.05514-1.96=-0.85
Power=pnorm(Z(power))=0.196
```

So can I say with current sample size, I have 20% power to detect the significant associations between x and y with current effect size.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious for everyone else, but: power (in this context) refers to binary hypothesis tests (*p* values), not to the precision of the estimation of the coefficient/effect size.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "no" but not for the reason in vafisher's answer.

The correct formula for the power of a two-sided hypothesis test for a single regression coefficient is 
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{power}=&\operatorname{Pr}\left(t_{\mathrm{df}} \le -\frac{D}{\operatorname{se}\left[D\right]} - {t}_{\mathrm{df},\frac{\alpha}{2}} \right)+\\&\operatorname{Pr}\left(t_{\mathrm{df}} > -\frac{D}{\operatorname{se}\left[D\right]} + {t}_{\mathrm{df},\frac{\alpha}{2}}  \right)
\end{align}$$

where $D$ is the effect size, in this case $D=\hat{\beta}-\beta_0=\hat{\beta}$. This is given in the appendix of Dupont and Plummer (1998) ([pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.biostat.washington.edu/~yanez/b578D/materials/dupontplummer.pdf&ei=fJmmU7uWMMvlsASUxoGABw&usg=AFQjCNEHqehT8Tqeu9ph8izEqyuwFbP8cQ&sig2=MJx9gMCNQ9WJXde56zRnoA)), equation (A1) on p. 599, and in [these notes](http://www.stat.osu.edu/~ekaizar/courses/528/notes/12_power_calculations.pdf).

The "Z" version of this test is just the normal approximation to the t-test. Note that the t-squared test (i.e. the $\chi^2$ test) is equivalent to the nested F test of regression models that differ by a single coefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, no. The t-statistic you're looking at is the square root of the F discussed in this post: [What is the power of the regression F test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/what-is-the-power-of-the-regression-f-test) for the removal of a single independent variable.

Comment: The F-test removing a single variable is equivalent to a t-test: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55236/prove-f-test-is-equal-to-t-test-squared